# After transform.colortransform on mc, can't change textfield's color within mc

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textfield, movieclip, colortransform

I'm trying to change the color of a textfield that is inside of a movie clip, in a game. I change the color of the movie clip using this:

> var newColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();//color change
>
> newColor.color = 0x000000;
>
> circle.transform.colorTransform = newColor;

This works fine. However, I have added a textfield to circle, using this.addChild(), called A (public var A:TextField = new TextField(), which I have set to have a white color).
When I try to change the color of the text of A, using A.textColor = 0xFFFFFF, after using transform.colortransform, the color of the circle is still black and A becomes black too. No matter how often I call to change A's text color, it stays black.

Any one have any idea about what could be going wrong?

Thanks,
FF

Answer (score 1):

ColorTransforms are applied to all contents (and children) of a MovieClip.  It doesn't matter what color the TextField (or any other DisplayObject child) is, it will all render black.  Your options are:

- Apply the black colorTransform not to the parent MovieClip, but to the circle you want to turn black.
- Move the TextField out of the parent MovieClip

This is the same as geometric transforms - if you rotate the parent movieclip, the children inside are all rotated accordingly.

Comment: So, once the color transform is applied to the movie clip, it is impossible for me to change the color of the text field?

Comment: Short answer, yes. You will be changing the color of the text, but not see it because the color transform of the parent will hide the change. 
What you need to do is make the circle and text children of the same parent, then apply the color transform only to the circle.